# Convert Arcminute / Second to decimal (irregular format)

Tags: r, gps

I'm dealing with some irregular and poorly thought through data with GPS coordinates and I need to make them more useable and pipeable.

I've been basing my work on the angle2dec function that I found on here:

```
angle2dec <- function(angle) {
  angle <- as.character(angle)
  x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(angle, split=' '))

  #decimal points where they should and should not be here
  #causes my issue as i can't use a consistent string split
  #character.  splitting the first 3 '.' occurrences might work

  x <- apply(x, 1L, function(y) {
    y <- as.numeric(y)
    y[1] + y[2]/60 + y[3]/3600
  })
  return(x)
}
```

However my data is not nicely formatted.  A coordinate looks like this:

```
'53.17.35.852'
```

The ang2dec function works for coordinates that follow this format:

```
ang2dec('53 17 35.852') = 53.29329
```

(This is the correct result)

Clearly the problem is the poor choice of formatting of the coordinate.  Can anyone suggest a way that I can convert the first format of coordinate into the second or propose changes to the ang2dec function that would include the functionality that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created a function you can pass this to your desired vector using apply functions.
>   This will help you to format your current format into desired one.

```
library(data.table)
format.fun<-function(x){
  y<-as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(tstrsplit(x, split = "\\.",names = T))))
  y<-lapply(y, function(x){
    temp<- paste(x[1],x[2],x[3], sep = " ")
    temp<- paste(temp, x[4], sep = ".")
    temp
  })
  unlist(y)
}
```